# Necesito ayuda para optimizar codigo en python flask

Tags: python, bucle-for, flask

Buenas estoy programando unas cosas en Python con el microframework Flask. Y en un momento del código debo declarar 25 variables (desde q1 hasta q25) con el "prefijo" q + numero de la pregunta y hacer que cada prefijo q con su respectivo numero retorne un valor insertado en un formulario.
Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    age = request.form['age']
    sex = request.form['sex']
    q1 = request.form['q1']
    q2 = request.form['q2']
    q3 = request.form['q3']
    q4 = request.form['q4']
    q5 = request.form['q5']
    q6 = request.form['q6']
    q7 = request.form['q7']
    q8 = request.form['q8']
    q9 = request.form['q9']
    q10 = request.form['q10']
    q11 = request.form['q11']
```

(..sigue hasta q25)
pero me di cuenta que podria resolver eso de alguna forma iterando con un for loop. Aunque no se me ocurre como ya que soy bastante novato. Si alguien me pudiese esclarecer seria genial. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Porque no simplemente, cuando necesites un valor de tu formulario, por ejemplo el valor de `age`, lo obtienes y ya (`request.form['age']`), veo innecesario crear tantas variables para guardar los valores de tu formulario si simplemente los puedes obtener cuando los necesites, así: `request.form[value]`. Es complicarse demasiado.

Comment: porque despues tengo que usar esas variables para hacer operaciones matematicas y si tuvieses que declarar la request quedaria enorme el codigo en ese momento.

Comment: Entonces, en variables puedes guardar resultados de pequeñas partes de la operacion matematica, para posteriormente utilisarlas completando la operacion matematica "principal", de esta manera quedaria mas legible el codigo y no quedaria enorme el codigo, como dices. Ademas de que crear tantas variables es costoso y no es nada optimo hacerlo.